# Decoding a Stripe return object

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm working with stripe and I lack experience extracting information from the json objects that the system returns. the data is in so many levels and I'm not clear how many of those I have to refer to in order to retreive data. Here's and example of the first part of an object up to an actual bit of data:

```
Stripe\Collection Object ( 
  [_requestParams:protected] => Array ( 
    [limit] => 3 
  ) 
  [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object ( 
    [headers] => Array ( ) 
    [apiKey] => sk_test_WLW9c2qhiZAFUgSgHI2tF2kR 
  ) 
  [_values:protected] => Array ( 
    [object] => list 
    [data] => Array ( 
      [0] => Stripe\Account Object ( 
        [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object ( 
          [headers] => Array ( ) 
          [apiKey] => some-key
        ) 
      [_values:protected] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1112222333 
        [object] => account 
        [name] => John
```

So how would I write out the variable that would get me "John"? I'm looking for a principle here, so I can apply it to other variables.

Comment: Assuming this object is contained in some variable that we'll call `$ob`; it would look something like this:

`$ob->_values->data->_values->name` (I think?)

Though, if you're using the PHP Bindings provided by Stripe, accessing a collection like the results of the List Accounts Endpoint ( https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_accounts ), it would look more like this:

`$ob->data[0]->business_name`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is the case. It's the data variable, which you can iterate.$all = Stripe\Account::all(array("limit" => 100));
 foreach ($all->data as $account) {
  echo '<br />'.$account->id;
 }